# How to change the orientation of UIWindow in iPad

Tags: ios

I want to create something like that a UIView slide down for the status bar in iPad. But it only work in portrait mode. When I rotate the iPad to landscape mode, the UIView still slide as portrait mode.

Comment: Could you be less ambiguous, and maybe some screenshots?

Comment: Are you returning "YES" from the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method in the view controller, so that the app knows to support both orientations?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are adding it to window

```
If you add an additional view controller's UIView property to UIWindow (at the same level as your primary view controller) via the following:

[myWindow addSubview:anotherController.view];

this additional view controller will not receive rotation events and will never rotate. Only the first view controller added to UIWindow will rotate.
```

So try this :

```
UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
if (!window) 
    window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
[[[window subviews] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:myView];
```

Comment: @ghazi_jaffary did you get the answer of your above question?

Answer (score -1):

You should try:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

Just put it in your viewcontroller.m file.